# Is there a way to loop through my established TextBoxes and define each .Text?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a group of 8 `TextBoxes` in a `WinForm` and I've created an object array for them to be contained. In the initialization of the `Form`, I want to set each `TextBox.text` to `Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents"` to show the default file-path for each box. These boxes are used for displaying which file is to be loaded based on user input.

Currently the code looks like this:

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    BWGPTextBox.Text = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents"
    BWBRTextBox.Text = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents"
    ChGPTextBox.Text = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents"
    ChBRTextBox.Text = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents"
    CCGPTextBox.Text = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents"
    CCBRTextBox.Text = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents"
    PPGPTextBox.Text = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents"
    PPBRTextBox.Text = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents"
End Sub
```

Is there a way I can have it operate within a For Loop (similar to below, except this does not work) to define each box? This way I can also modify each box uniformly, such as `[Excel.Application].[Excel.Workbook].Open(TextBoxesList(x).Text)`

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Dim TextBoxesList As Object = {BWGPTextBox, BWBRTextBox, _
                                      ChBRTextBox, ChGPTextBox, _
                                      CCGPTextBox, CCBRTextBox, _
                                      PPGPTextBox, PPBRTextBox}
    For Each x In TextBoxesList
        TextBoxesList(x).GetType() ' = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `As Object` is almost always the wrong approach since it boxes the objects you are trying to use. `Dim TextBoxesList As TextBox() = ...` will create an array of textboxes *and* allow you to access textbox properties

Comment: @Plutonix To create this array and define it, would `Dim TextBoxesList As TextBox() = {TextBox1, TextBox2, [....] }` work? If so, would `TextBoxesList(x).text = "put text here"` work as well?

Comment: @Plutonix After using `TextBoxesList(x).text = "put text here"`, I'm getting an error saying `Value of Type System.Windows.Forms.Textbox Cannot be Converted to Integer`. Do you know why this is the error? (Sorry, I'm new to visual studio from VBA, so I'm not used to deciphering errors yet...)

Comment: `x` is not an integer since you are not using `For x As Int32 =0 To TextBoxesList.Count-1`  each x ***is*** a textbox.  A clearer way to loop for that would be `For Each tb As TextBox In TextBoxList`.  then just `tb.Text = "foo"`

Comment: I'm now getting a `TypeInitializationException was Unhandled` error. The Immediate Window is saying "A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occured in WindowsApplication1.exe"

Comment: you cant reference the array until it is built...not sure where you are getting the NRE

Comment: @Plutonix Instead of placing the `Dim` statement for the `TextBoxesList` in the variable declaration section (above all `subs`, below `class`), placing it within the `New()` method seemed to work exactly as needed. Does this mean that the variables in `New()` are processed before the containing class variables?

Comment: That array will exist only in that method, if you need to use it elsewhere it needs form level scope

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117840/discussion-between-munkeeface-and-plutonix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing specific types As Object is often a mistake since it hides the real type being stored:

```
Dim TextBoxesList As Object = {BWGPTextBox, BWBRTextBox, 
                                  ChBRTextBox, ChGPTextBox, 
                                  CCGPTextBox, CCBRTextBox, 
                                  PPGPTextBox, PPBRTextBox}
```

The resulting array stores Objects which prevents you from accessing TextBox specific properties.  Start with a typed array:

```
' DECLARE the array at the form level:
Private TextBoxesList As TextBox()
....
' initialize it AFTER the constructor runs:
TextBoxesList = {BWGPTextBox, BWBRTextBox, 
                                  ChBRTextBox, ChGPTextBox, 
                                  CCGPTextBox, CCBRTextBox, 
                                  PPGPTextBox, PPBRTextBox}

' then loop:
For Each tb As TextBox in TextBoxesList 
    tb.Text = "foo"          
Next
```

Stored and iterated `As TextBox` allows `TextBox` properties to be easily accessed.  You can also loop by index:

```
For n As Int32 = 0 to TextBoxesList.Count-1
    TextBoxesList(n).Text = "foo"          
Next
```